# How do I setup rampart with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis, policy, rampart

I have a simple Axis2 web service which I want to add security to, I am using tomcat and the webservice is deployed and working properly
So I have a few questions, do I need to copy the rampart jar files into the client/service build paths?
Where do I put the rampart modules and policy file?

I would appreciate any help or a step by step guide

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to learn these is to look at rampart samples http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/rampart/branches/1_6/modules/rampart-samples/policy . There you can see how clients and services are configured.